# Keep input from evaluating in a pop-up box?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following mma code:

```
$ButtonOptions = {Method -> "Queued"};
Button["Get List of IDs",
  ai = ToString@Input["Please Enter ID#s", {}];
  ai = StringReplace["ai", "\[Times]" -> ","];
  Print@ai,
  Background -> Yellow, Sequence @@ $ButtonOptions
  ]
```

I need users to input multiple ID numbers in those brackets when the input window pops up. They like to use Excel and paste in a column, but this results in a new paragraph for each ID number (which Mathematica converts to a space, and then to multiplication, and then it multiplies all the IDs together). I need some way to keep the input from evaluating when they enter it without having `Hold` actually show up in the input box so the `StringReplace` operation will work and get rid of all the line breaks before Mathematica multiplies the IDs together.

Comment: I added `$ButtonOptions={Method -> "Queued"}` and a semicolon before `Print` so that the code will run as is (but still not do what you want).

Answer (score 5):

How about something using `InputString`?

```
Button["Get List of IDs",
 ai = InputString["Please Enter ID#s", {}];
 ai = DeleteCases[StringSplit[ai, WhitespaceCharacter | ","], ""];
 Print[ai],
 Method -> "Queued"]
```

Of course, you probably want to have more checks on the types of Ids. In the above code I used `StringSplit` to separate the string at spaces, tabs, newlines and commas - but this is probably a bit too simplistic and not robust enough for real life use.